# How do i display colored terminal output in readable form in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, powershell, electron, child-process

This code tells electron to run a command and prints the output to the console and render the same output in DOM using react-js

```js
import Titlebar from "./components/Titlebar/Titlebar"
import { useState } from "react"

let shellOutput = []
const [currentShellOutput, setCurrentShellOutput] = useState(shellOutput)
ElectronAPI.execShellCommands(["spicetify apply"])
ElectronAPI.receive("sendToRenderer/shell-output", (outputString) => {
    console.log(outputString)
    setCurrentShellOutput((value) => {
        return value.concat([outputString])
    })
})

export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Titlebar></Titlebar>
            {currentShellOutput.map((output) => (
                <p className="terminal-output">{output}</p>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

Code that actually runs the command using nodejs

```js
export function execShellCommands(commands) {
    let shellProcess = spawn("powershell.exe", [commands[0]])

    shellProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("sendToRenderer/shell-output", data.toString())
    })
    shellProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("sendToRenderer/shell-output", "stderr: " + data.toString())
    })
    shellProcess.on("exit", () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("sendToRenderer/shell-output", "shell-exited")
        commands.shift()
        if (0 < commands.length) {
            execShellCommands(commands)
        }
    })
}
```

The output is printed perfectly in devtools console but in the DOM its weird:

[image: output]

Comment: How can you use `setState` hook outside a functional component? It make me confus

Comment: This code is solid js, i translated to react so more people will answer, but totally forgot to put useState inside the functional component.